# Does the minimum spanning tree tell us anything useful about evolutionary ancestry?

Tags: phylogenetics, homology

*Question migrated from bioinformatics stackexchange due to lack of interest.*

I'm new to bioinformatics and have been reading through a [bioinformatics book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0144NZ2EC), and it seems calculating a phylogenetic tree is quite a complicated process.

I'm wondering if generating the minimum spanning tree (MST) from a similarity matrix would provide a decent approximation to the actual phylogenetic tree, i.e. provide some information on the evolutionary ancestry of a collection of organisms?  My thinking is that animals diverging from ancient ancestors will always be farther away than animals that diverged recently, so the MST will at least show me what animals are genetically related and which are genetically distant.

I realize this is not quite the same thing as a phylogenetic tree, but it seems to give me some of the same information provided by a phylogenetic tree, namely which animals are closely genetically related and which are distant relatives.

For reference, I'm measuring similarity based on the normalized compression distance (NCD) metric.  The metric is defined in "[Clustering by Compression](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1412045)" by Cilibrasi and Vitanyi.

Here is an example MST using the dataset from the referenced paper.  Some parts make sense from my rudimentary knowledge of biology, like the clustering of primates.  Other parts are new to me, and I'm not sure if the relationships are just an accidental feature of the metric, MST, or if real.  For instance, cows are more related to whales instead of horses according to the MST, cats and dogs appear to have evolved from seals or visa versa, and pigs are related to a wide variety of animals: ranging from bats to rabbits to whales.

Note, the 'randgen' nodes are randomly generated DNA sequences that I added to the dataset as a sanity check.  As expected, they are off on a branch by themselves instead of mixed into the population of real animal DNA sequences.  The reason why they are clustered is because I repeat each DNA sequence 40 times to amplify the signal, and repeated short random subsequences become compressible.  The random DNA sequences are probably clustered because they tend to share random subsequences, while the mammal DNA sequences are orderly and have fewer random subsequences.

Here is the repo to reproduce the tree.
https://github.com/yters/ncd

[image]

Comment: If i search for anything as distant as a mouse and a seal i get 5000 results. I did an OTT parser but i dont know what a similarity matrix is... Dont know why or how to apply similarity to phylogeny!

Comment: Have you tried comparing your tree to phylogeny? From a cursory look the answer seems to obviously be "no".

Comment: Whales are artiodactyls just like cows and pigs, so that actually makes sense. but from looking at it they must be using a really shallow dataset because they have some strange clustering. Also the fact all your randoms are clustering makes me wonder if they are really random.

Comment: @John the reason the randoms are clustering is because I have to repeat each string 40 times to get enough compression.  So, the repetition causes the randoms to cluster, because most other sequences don't have as many random subsequences.  Their subsequences are more orderly.

Comment: @com.prehensible similarity matrix is created by measuring similarity between each unordered pair using the NCD metric I reference.  I repeat each sequence 40 times before measuring similarity to get enough of a signal for the metric to work.

Comment: @BryanKrause that is a good suggestion, but I'm also wondering about the informativeness of a minimum spanning tree in general.  It would seem the MST should show how closely/distantly related different organisms are.  Hence my question about the weird clusterings that John mentioned.  Basically, the MST seems to be much simpler than the tree construction algorithms I've read about, so it'd be great if the MST is phylogenetically meaningful.

Comment: Well, for a start, it shows nothing about ancestry. A phylogenetic tree shows where modern species exist relative to their most recent common ancestors. That concept is completely missing here.

Comment: I agree with @BryanKrause. For species relationships, this is absolutely meaningless, showing nothing about common ancestry. It could _perhaps_ be interpretable as, for example, an unrooted haplotype network, but if there is no explicit interpretation in number of inferred differences (and of course, given the level of divergence summarised here) this doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: @NatWH if I have organisms A, B and C, and A and B are linked on the tree, while A and C are far away, can't I infer that A and B have a recent common ancestor and A and C have an ancient common ancestor?  I think this is valid reasoning because the MST is formed from the shortest edges, i.e. most genetically similar organisms, and two organisms that share a recent common ancestor should be more genetically similar than two organisms that have an ancient common ancestor.  Is there a flaw in this logic?

Comment: @yters Take an example where A and B are closely related, and C is more distant from A and B (let's say A is a tiger, B is a lion, and C is a gorilla). In your map, A and B will be connected, sure, but where is C? It should be equally far from A and B. In your map it will instead connect to either A or B. That connection is not meaningful. It should connect hierarchically to (A and B). Phylogeny has this, your map does not.

Comment: Well yes, because rates of evolution frequently vary between lineages, and genetic (dis)similarity may not cleanly map to species relationships. So you might get _some_ signal, but most of it is probably meaningless. For example, your figure above is telling me that fin whales are as closely related to blue whales as blue whales are to Hippopotami, but it's fairly uncontroversial that cetaceans are monophyletic. We already have fast algorithms to infer inaccurate trees.

Comment: For another example from your actual example, it looks like a chimp is connected to a platypus through a rhino? What does that even mean?

Comment: Even worse, to get from guinea pig to mouse we go through blue whale and pig?

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes, it seems to only give me one directional inferences.  If C is far away from A and B then I can infer it is from a more distant common ancestor.  But, if B and C are both connected to A, then I cannot infer much about the distance of the common ancestor in that case.  I also agree my tree has a bunch of weird paths, but I'm not sure if this means MST is meaningless or that evolution is much weirder than I first suspected.

Comment: @NatWH the branch lengths are not meaningful in my graph, so I can only make inferences based on number of nodes on the path.  This means my graph says a dormouse is more closely related to a cow than to a mouse, but it does not say a blue whale is as closely related to a fin whale as to a cow.

Comment: Actually yes, it does - because you're confusing distances for relationships. Relationships are only ever discrete, defined in terms of degrees of common ancestry. The branch lengths do not matter in terms of statements of relatedness. So your graph explicitly does say that a blue whale is as closely related to a fin whale as it is to a cow, because they each are separated by one edge. If you wanted it to say otherwise, you would have to introduce a node representing the hypothetical ancestor to the tree, and @BryanKrause points out.

Comment: Basically, any algorithm that places an extant taxon on a node, not a tip, is probably not inferring a phylogeny.

Comment: @NatWH great point.  I have updated my question to not be so attached to the phylogenetic tree aspect, but whether a MST tells us anything about the evolutionary ancestry.  The reason I'm focused on the MST is 1) it's easy, fast, understandable algorithm and 2) seems to hypothetically provide some information about evolutionary ancestry.  But, your point that evolution rates can vary dramatically would imply that the MST is meaningless.  However, then I wonder how is it possible to infer anything about lineage based on DNA sequences if the rates are so variable?

Comment: @yters there are already fast, distant-based approximations for phylogenetic trees - look up Neighbour-Joining. But they are weak for the reasons we have discussed. Instead, we use more sophisticated models which can account for variable patterns of substitutions, rates across sites, and even rates across lineages, implemented via maximum likelihood or Bayesian inference. The reason that phylogenetic inference is frequently slow is precisely _because_ the process we are attempting to understand is intensely complicated, and short cuts are often suboptimal.

Comment: I think @NatWh has explained this very well. I also think the updated question title is a bit worthless. Can it be useful? Well, maybe if you only have a group of closely related species it could give you some hints but it's not particularly efficient and there are other better tools. I'm not sure why you are reinventing this wheel.

Comment: @NatWH simplicity is also a reason I was looking at MST because the problem with an extremely complex process is that it is easy to bake in a lot of assumptions about how evolution works.  The more complex the reconstruction the more likely we are making the data fit our model instead of the other way around.  I will look into the neighbor joining method.  A bit more complicated, but it seems straightforward to implement and the wiki page has a worked example.  Thanks!

Comment: That would be all well and good if we didn't already have solid demonstrations that attempting to oversimplify this process leads to totally erroneous results (like the ones in your network). Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @NatWH mostly b/c barrier to entry and understanding for standard approaches looks quite high, and they seem to have a whole lot of assumptions built into them.  Given how frequently and significantly evolutionary theory keeps changing, the built in assumptions seem like premature optimization.  I don't want to spend months and possibly years learning an outdated theory of evolution.  And, as I mentioned, just thinking about the logic of evolutionary lineage, the simple MST seems like it should provide some insight.  At any rate, the current answer provides a good way to check the MST.

Comment: I am not sure that you have thought about the logic of evolutionary lineage, or you have fundamentally misunderstood what I and other commenters have been saying. Your diagram is not a phylogeny, and doesn't show anything about evolutionary history or even lineage, because it implies that extant taxa evolved from other extant taxa, which is false.

Comment: @NatWH the main sticking point is the rate of evolution.  But, even if there is high variance in rate, there are still certain patterns in the MST.  For instance, organisms with the highest rates should be farthest from everything else, and organisms with the slowest rates and common ancestor should be closest to each other.  Organisms like bacteria will have extremely high evolution rates, and organisms with long lifespans and few children like humans and elephants have very low evolution rates.  Thus, an MST with humans, elephants and bacteria will form three unmixed clusters.

Comment: @yters If you think the main sticking point is the rate of evolution you are definitely not understanding the criticism. The main sticking point is that you've generated something that is nothing like a phylogeny. I'm also uncertain what you mean about evolutionary theory changing...the major principles have been constant for decades. All that has changed recently are minor nitpicks.

Comment: @BryanKrause the problem is I'm not a very clear communicator :)  Yes, the MST is not a phylogenetic tree.  The initial phrasing caused this confusion, which I've corrected.  The MST seems to tell us something about evolutionary lineage, based on the simple mathematical reasoning I've offered.  My understanding of modern evolution comes from a couple books, such as the bioinformatics book I linked in my question.  I've also been reading through Koonin's 'Logic of Chance' and Kauffman's 'The Origins of Order'.  The evolution they describe is not the kind I read about in 'Origin of Species'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graphic is omitting nodes of the tree, branching points, which are essential for trees and phylogeny.

When you read the data file, you should count the brackets ((( ))) because they signify where the tree has nodes, common ancestors.

You should generate simple phylogeny trees, prior to doing complex data mining for similarity. The names are in latin? there are genetic distance numbers? What format and data are you using? You have given the common animal names. you may have to use a database of common-and-latin-names to be ables to search "tiger"... that database will return "panthera tigris tigris"... And then you can start crawling up and down the tree branches to search for animals related to tigris tigris, by counting brackets and marking species close to that name.

To prevent the tree exploding to 5000 animals, you can 
1/define a search depth. Depth 5, Five, will not go further than five brackets: (((((panthera_tigris_tigris)(lion)(cheetah)))))
2/represent a random fraction of the species (1/100 gives 50 animals from a 5000 tree)
3/use statistics measures to select certain animals based on data mining.

If you want to travel from whales to monkeys, you will have most of the mammalian family, and you will be able to count nodes and brackets by the dozens.

Not that parsing 5000 species has a big computational load that can take 1 hour to read through once, let alone 40 times!

Whichever statistics you are using to measure similarity, number of brackets / genetic distance numbers, you should have once represented trees as branches, nodes and leaves, because that is what tree data is meant to represent.

I'd recommend that you draw a tree using nodes and random animal selection, like 1% chance the animal is drawn in the final tree. When your tree has branches and is drawing OK, change the 1% selection line for the complex MST / MCD selection.

Comment: This is a great suggestion to run the MST on a known phylogenetic tree.  Currently, I am just using a collection of DNA sequences.  If you could provide a link to a database that has both the tree and the DNA sequences for comparison, I'll mark this as accepted.